# hdparm errors: bad/missing sens data (no hdparm commands working)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, hdparm

I recently installed 4 Seagate 4tb SAS Exos 7e8 drives into my Dell r410 running Ubuntu Server 19.04. I am getting an error from hdparm everytime I try to run a hdparm command. The one command that works is -Tt for testing speed, but it still gives the errors. It always spits out this:

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 72 05 20 00 00 00 00 ic 02 06 00 00 cf 00 00 00 03 02 00 01 80 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 72 05 20 00 00 00 00 ic 02 06 00 00 cf 00 00 00 03 02 00 01 80 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
```

This happens for every single hdparm command, and `-I`
 will not give me any data except an the error above.

I am trying to think of a couple problems and there are two that I think could be the culprit:

```
1. It is a Self-Encrypting drive and it might be locked, but the speed test still works which I would expect to not work if it were locked.
2. It is frozen, this might be the problem, if so, how do I fix it?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `hdparm` is simply the wrong tool for your disks. They are SCSI (SAS) disks and you are trying to use a program that is entirely built around ATA commands. They literally do not speak the same language.

For SCSI you have `sg_*` tools found in *sg3-utils*. For example, `sg_inq` to show disk identity, `sg_start` to spin up/down, `sg_turs` and `sg_requests` for status. The usual `smartctl` will work with SCSI disks, although somewhat differently.

(The kernel performs some ATA/SCSI translation, but that's for the opposite direction: i.e. allowing programs to issue SCSI commands to ATA disks. That allows some of the sg3-utils to work on ATA, but not the other way around.)

Seagate self-encrypting drives [appear to use](https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/manual/Interface%20manuals/100515636b.pdf) TCG OPAL, so `sedutil-cli` should work with them. (If you tried to set an "ATA password", that wouldn't have worked anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, I would like to mention that you can use the`sdparm` utility with SCSI disks. 
Install with `sudo apt install sdparm`

Get all parameters/settings with `sudo sdparm -l -a /dev/sdX`
Here `-a` gets all output fields  and `-l` gets the long output i.e. explanation of the output fields.